# Responder chain - different behavior with touchesMoved vs. touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say you create two view controllers, A and B. A has a segue to B (which segue specifically I don't think matters here, as the outcome seems to be the same. I'll use push as example.). A has the following implementation:

```
class A: UIViewController {

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      print("A received a begin touch")
  }
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      print("A received a move touch")
  }
}
```

In B, you have:

```
class B: UIViewController {

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      print("B received a begin touch")
  }
}
```

This here will block any touches from going to ViewController A. Even when there is a move touch, A does not recieve it.

However, if instead the code for B was:

```
class B: UIViewController {

  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      print("B received a move touch")
  }
}
```

Then A's "began touch" prints, and both A and B's "move touch" prints. So to summarize, when implementing just `touchesBegan` in class B, the only thing printing to the console is "B received a begin touch". When implementing just `touchesMoved` in class B, the console prints "A received a begin touch" followed by an alternating pattern of both A and B receiving a move touch.

So what's the reason for this difference? Why does `touchesBegan` override in B stop the `touchesMoved` method from firing in A? And why doesn't the `touchesMoved` method in B stop the `touchesMoved` method from firing in A? I saw in the docs that you must override all touch methods if you don't call super, but I still don't get why that would be necessary here.

Comment: I'm scared of down votes and I have not read the docs in a while, but i don't think you are supposed to call super in your touch handling methods are you? What if you delete the super call, do you get the same issue?

Comment: @D.C. you are totally getting at something here! I've edited my post to explain the changes, though it seems to be against Apple's recommendations in the docs. It's strange: if I remove the calls to super and just implement `touchesBegan` in `B`, it silences both overriden methods from A, including the `touchesMoved` method.

Comment: I assume `B` is presented partially on top of `A` and that's why you're expecting them both to get notified?

Comment: @rb612, i done same demo but working fine for me. please check twice and make sure you make any mistake

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior of showing both A and B's move touch. Is your B a child view controller of A?

Comment: @Cosyn do you have only the touchesMoved method in both view controllers and not the touchesBegan method. This is a necessary component of reproducing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating I think I might be onto something.

I've created an Xcode project to put your example into work, both using UIViewcontroller and UIViews.. to see how it behaves. Then I wanted to recreate the same "results" using Swift patterns we all know, as if I were to implement UIViews/UIViewController responder chain. I added a link to these files below.

The final behaviour is obtained combining subclass + protocol with standard implementation, so when the event chain arrives, it makes a difference which methods you implemented. Assume all the events are delivered via a fund called stuff() and consider the following.

```
enum State: Int {
    case None
    case Start
    case Doing
    case End
}

protocol StuffTouches {
    var superStuff: StuffTouches? {get set}
    var gesturingState: State {get set}
    func begin()
    func moves()
    func ended()
    mutating func stuff()
}

extension StuffTouches {
    mutating func stuff() {
        switch gesturingState {
        case .None:
            gesturingState = .Start
            print("Protocol \(self) BEGIN")
            begin()
        case .Start:
            gesturingState = .Doing
            print("Protocol \(self) Moves")
            moves()
        case .End:
            gesturingState = .None
            print("Protocol \(self) Ended")
            ended()
        case .Doing:
            print("Protocol \(self) Moves")
            moves()
        }
        if gesturingState == .None {
            gesturingState = .Start

        }

    }
    func moves() {
        print("Protocol \(self) Moves")
        superStuff?.moves()
    }
    func ended() {
        print("Protocol \(self) Ended")
        superStuff?.ended()
    }

}

class BaseStuff: StuffTouches {
    var superStuff: StuffTouches?
    var gesturingState: State = .None


    func begin() {
        print("Base \(self) BEGIN")
    }

    func moves() {
        print("Base \(self) Moves")
    }

    func ended() {
        print("Base \(self) Ended")
    }
}

class TypeCStuff: BaseStuff {
    override func moves() {
        print("C Moves")
    }
}

var stuff = TypeCStuff() as BaseStuff
stuff.superStuff = BaseStuff()
print("Event 1 - Touches begin")
stuff.stuff()
print("Event 2 - Continues")
stuff.stuff()
print("3")
stuff.stuff()
print("4")
stuff.stuff()
print("5")
stuff.stuff()
```

The printout is:

```
Event 1 - Touches begin
Protocol __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff BEGIN
Base __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff BEGIN
Event 2 - Continues
Protocol __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff Moves
C Moves
3
Protocol __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff Moves
C Moves
4
Protocol __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff Moves
C Moves
5
Protocol __lldb_expr_7.TypeCStuff Moves
C Moves
```

Which emulates exactly the behaviour you find on the events you describe.

For the research I created a project and a playground, find them on [github](https://github.com/TeamPacMan/ResponderChain-TouchesBegan-TouchesMoves)

Back to the original question: I'm not sure what is the Responder implementation, but I believe one the reasons Apple asks you to implement both is that the default implementation use a combination of protocol, extensions and subclass, for which if you don't override all methods, you might be cut out of the chain as you can see in the following:

```
protocol ThisProtocol {

}

extension ThisProtocol {
    func test() {
        print("Protocol")
    }

    func someOtherMethods() {
        print("Protocol 2")
    }

    func ultimateTest() {
        test()
        someOtherMethods()
    }
}

struct ThisStruct: ThisProtocol {

    func test1() {
        test()
    }

    func test2() {
        ultimateTest()
    }

    func test() {
        print("ThisStruct")
        (self as ThisProtocol).test()
    }
}

ThisStruct().test2()
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Protocol
Protocol 2
```

(despite the fact that the func test() is implemented in ThisStruct)

IF, instead, you call test1(), you will see that ThisStruct.test() is correctly called.

Comment: So what's the reason of this behavior?

Comment: @Cosyn I added some description and an example. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the responder chain works. It works the same with `UIView` objects. If you have a Button B as a subview of a Button A, then if you tap the area of button B, it gets the touch instead of button A. Button A doesn't register the tap.

Apparently Apple's implementation works something like

```
var view = self
while (!view.respondsToSelector(#selector(touchesBegan...)) {
    view = view.superview
}
view.touchesBegan(...)
```

Apple documentation also states about `touchesBegan`:

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, even if your implementations do nothing.

Which means that implementing only one method has undefined results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was really about if there was a reason why touchesBegan worked as expected but not touchesMoved. Any input on that?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer is about that. You're not supposed to override only one method according to the documentation. If you're overriding only some methods weird things may occur and they may be different weird things depending on iOS version and other factors